# аснихронный __exit__

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, асинхронность, asyncio

Я использую `aiohttp`. Мне необходимо сделать закрытие сессии при уничтожении объекта. Но это запрещено делать асинхронно. Есть ли способ реализовать это в python?

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        await self.session.close()

    async def r(self):
        resp = await self.session.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
```

Возможно, именно для этого используется асинхронный контекст. Если я прав, объясните, как им пользоваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Есть в PEP492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with) `__aexit__()` в python3.5+

> An example of an asynchronous context manager:
>
> class AsyncContextManager:
>       async def **aenter**(self):
>           await log('entering context')
>
> ```
> async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
>     await log('exiting context')
> ```
>
> New Syntax A new statement for asynchronous context managers is proposed:
>
> ```
> async with EXPR as VAR:
>     BLOCK
> ```

но если очень хочется, то

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
...
    async_to_sync(self.session.close)()
```